# Ask about recommendation

Tags: discussion

I know that here at SE I cant ask recommendation of products and so. I have a printer that I wanna buy and I want to know if it's good. Where should I post this question in order to get some smart people to take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Great question! 3DPrinting SE attracts a lot of new Stack Exchange network users, which unfortunately can come with questions that don't always meet the Q&A style for the network that this site tries to uphold.

Questions like this are probably best asked in the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34216/the-hotbed-3d-printing) room. Currently, it's not very active, but hopefully if we have a few people interested in these more "off-topic" questions the activity will pick up. Pings are going to be a very useful tool if we're going to try and utilize the chat window more. Pinging some of the highly active users may help get quality answers to those off-topic questions.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your question could be acceptable.  What you want to avoid is "questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based".  That still leaves lots of other acceptable questions to ask like what printers have a specific feature or whether a specific printer has a specific feature. Note the word "specific".

There is also a [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) SE Beta that may work for you.